# Mysql Select Between values not including same values

Tags: mysql

I am trying to select data between two dates using:

```
SELECT `timein`,
       `date`
FROM   `clock`
WHERE  `eid` = '189'
       AND date BETWEEN '2018-10-01' AND '2018-10-31'
```

This provides me with all of the data, but I need to exclude selecting the same date.

For example:

```
Date: 2018-10-11 | Value: 1
Date: 2018-10-12 | Value: 2
Date: 2018-10-13 | Value: 3
Date: 2018-10-11 | Value: 4 **<-- Do not select**
```

Comment: How come you want Value 1 and not Value 4?

Comment: Please add relevant tags only. I have removed the rest of the irrelevant ones.

Comment: The query has the columns timein and date, and the sample data has date and value... In different order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a `GROUP BY`, use `MIN()` to pick the lowest timein value:

```
SELECT date, min(timein)
FROM clock
WHERE eID = '189' AND date BETWEEN '2018-10-01' AND '2018-10-31'
group by date
```